# Varying skiprows argument for individual worksheets when using pd.read_excel()

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have an excel-workbook with two worksheets which I want to import using `pandas`. I would like to use the `skiprows` argument, with 5 rows for the first sheet and 10 rows for the second sheet. `pd.read_excel()` returns a dictionary in case the excel file has several worksheets. Can I pass the `skiprows` argument as a list or similar to make it apply varying values for the individual sheets? I've tried this:

```
ret = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=[5, 10], sheet_name=None)
```

It looks like the `skiprows`-argument is simply ignored in this case.
Can I make it work somehow?

If yes, this can hopefully be generalized to other arguments too.

Comment: From the documentation it seems that for `skiprows` "An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x in [0, 2]`". You could try with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated to generalize to all arguments. You have to iterate on each sheets.

A possible solution:

```
sheets = {
    'Sheet1': {'skiprows': 5},   # add other parameters
    'Sheet2': {'skiprows': 10},  # according the documentation
}

def read_excel_sheets(filename, sheets):
    dfs = {}
    with pd.ExcelFile(filename) as xlsx:
        for sheet_name, params in sheets.items():
            dfs[sheet_name] = xlsx.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name, **params)
    return dfs

# The output is the same as pd.read_excel(filename, sheets=None)
dfs = read_excel_sheets('data.xlsx', sheets)
```